# Best way to add Dynamics Pivot Tables in an application

Tags: .net, sql-server, algorithm, entity-framework, pivot-table

I have to created a section for data analysis in a web application using pivot tables, .Net Framework and a few big DataSet stored in SQL Server.

I would like to know if the best way to create pivot tables is loading all the data from the DB and create the pivot table in the server side using common algorithms. Or, create an algorithm that dynamically creates a pivot query, send it to the DB and let it do all the work.

Should I do it the pivot table myself? Should I use Entity Framework?

Does creating a pivot query algorithm sound like a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

The code [Pivot-Grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/810267/Pivot-Grid-in-Asp-Net-MVC) worked good for me. You can give a try.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/810267/Pivot-Grid-in-Asp-Net-MVC